# CodenameOne - ObjectiveC Bridge - Method signature not found for selector

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use the Honeywell Captuvo SDK and gather that I need to setup a delegate call to handle the requests from the scanner but when I this code it causes a "Method signature not found for selector [setCaptuvoEventsProtocol:] on target null" on the setProperty line:

```
Pointer captuvoShared =eval("Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice").asPointer();
if (captuvoShared!=null)
{
     Objc.DelegateObject delegate = Objc.makeDelegate()
     .add("captuvoConnected", Method.create(Method.ArgType.Void ,args->
     {
        Log.p("Connected");   
        return null;
     }));
    Objc.setProperty(captuvoShared, "CaptuvoEventsProtocol", delegate);
}
else
  Log.p("Captuvo null!");
```

Comment: I think you need to use `captuvoShared.isNull()` not `captuvoShared == null` but I asked Steve to confirm. Also that begs the question of why `Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that the Captuvo class doesn't respond to the message "setCaptuvoEventsProtocol".  Looking at the [header for the Captuvo SDK](https://github.com/DataSplice/HoneywellScanner/blob/master/src/ios/Honeywell/Captuvo.h#L1113), it looks like you mean to call the `addCaptuvoDelegate:` message.

E.g.

```
Objc.eval(captuvoShared, "addCaptuvoDelegate:", delegate);
```

Note: `Objc.setProperty()` should only be used for setting properties of objects.  Use `Objc.eval()` when you want to send messages.  `Objc.setProperty()` is really just sugar that converts a property name into the corresponding `setPropName` message.  E.g. If you call `Objc.setProperty(myObject, "name", "Steve")`, it just calls `Objc.eval(myObject, "setName:", "Steve")` under the covers.  If there is no `setName:` message, then there is no writable "name" property.

Another note:  It is better to use `Objc.isNull(myPointer)` rather than `myPointer == null` since it will also check the case where it is a `Pointer` to Objective-c's `nil`.

One other thing you'll need to change is the `Method.create()` call.  Since the `captuvoConnected` message of the `CaptuvoEventsProtocol` protocol have a void return value and take no-args, you'll need to do:

```
.add("captuvoConnected", Method.create(Method.ArgType.Void , new Method.ArgType[0], args->
     {
        Log.p("Connected");   
        return null;
     }));
```

Notice the second parameter there.  I have just updated the CN1ObjcBridge lib to create another variant that will make this easier:

```
.add("captuvoConnected", Method.create(args->
     {
        Log.p("Connected");   
        return null;
     }));
```

If you want to use this simplified syntax, you can download the latest CN1ObjCBridge.cn1lib from [here](https://github.com/shannah/CN1ObjCBridge/blob/master/CN1ObjCBridgeDemo/lib/CN1ObjCBridge.cn1lib), or wait a couple days for it to be available in Codename One settings.